# Android Bluetooth Basic Code

Tags: java, android, mobile, bluetooth

I am trying to write an app which will interface with my microprocessor board, and ultimately control the direction and movements of a helicopter (for a school project).
I have never written an android app before, so I have downloaded the stuff from the website & created the basic app where you type something, press the button, and it returns what you wrote. And it makes sense and works for me.
Now I need to get the bluetooth working, but the instructions are not as clear as the beginning steps were. Can someone please supply me with the code to a basic app which uses bluetooth? I would really like to compile it, see how it works, and go through the code to better understand this stuff... And thank-you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at 
Android Dev
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

One good sample app at
http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

and

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/14768-android-bluetooth-bluetoothadmin-tutorial.html

All the best